# How to .skip() . take() elements on IList?

Tags: c#

Tried with :

```
IList<T> list= (from ...linq...).ToList();
list = list.Skip(0).Take(10);
```

but seems that there aren't those functions. Any other further way to do this?

Comment: What version of the .Net Framework are you compiling for?

Comment: What is your exact error? because that code currently won't compile... you can't do IList<T> unless T has come from your method or class declaration and you cannot assign the result of IEnumerable<T> to IList<T> you would need to do `list = list.Skip(0).Take(10).ToList()` also .Skip(0) is not actually needed it doesn't do anything you could just do `list=list.Take(10).ToList()`

Comment: Bob Vale : tried that method, but the message is the same : `cannot convert implicit System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> System.Collections.Generic.IList<T> explicit conversion`

Comment: So was the problem the ToList() all along?

Comment: yeah I didnt put ToList() at the end...

Comment: So if I fixed your problem why didn't you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: Didnt see your answer! You will get +1 :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First make sure you are referencing System.Linq.

Secondly the extension methods work with a stronly typed list.  so use `list.OfType<object>().Skip(0).Take(10)`

If you know the items in your list are of a particular type then replace object with that type.

Thirdly, Skip(0) is redundant.

Additionally your code example is trying to assign from a IEnumerable to an IList you need the ToList() on your result.

```
list = list.Skip(0).Take(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

have you got `System.Linq` referenced?

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Still won't work with IList, as the methods work on `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @iain are you sure about that are you definitely running it on an `IList` and not and `IList<T>`

Comment: Doesn't compile or doesn't return results? Can you paste the compiler error?

Comment: It Doesnt' compile. It says I cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> in System.Collections.Generic.IList<T> (missing cast)

Comment: pop .ToList() on the end of the LINQ that returns the IEnumerable?

Answer (score 5):

Those are method extensions that are defined in namespace System.Linq. Be sure to reference it:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Still won't work with IList, as the methods work on `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 4):

`Skip` and `Take` are extensions to `IEnumerable<T>`. As you're dealing with the (non-generic) `IList` these wont be available. However if you know what type is in your `IList` then this should work fine:

```
list.OfType<YourType>().Skip(1).Take(10)
```

The reason this works is that `OfType<T>` is an extension method on the non-generic `IEnumerable` (which `IList` inherits from) and return a generic `IEnumerable<T>`.

references:
  [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

Comment: my `IList` is generic (wath the updated topic). Also tried with `list.OfType<T>.Skip(0).Take(10);` but it doesnt works...

Answer (score 3):

If you mean on a non-generic `IList`, you need to use [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) or [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to obtain a generic sequence first. If you expect all the elements to be of the desired type, use `Cast`. If you want to ignore elements of the "wrong" type, use `OfType`. (I prefer `Cast` where possible, as I generally *want* to get an exception if my data isn't as expected.)

For example:

```
IList list = ...;
var elements = list.Cast<string>()
                   .Skip(10)
                   .Take(20);
```

You also need a reference to the System.Core assembly and a `using` directive for `System.Linq`.

EDIT: Now that we know you've got an `IList<T>`, the problem is clearer. It's not that Skip and Take aren't found, it's that they don't return an `IList<T>`. If you change your code to:

```
IEnumerable<T> list= (from ...linq...).ToList();
list = list.Skip(0).Take(10);
```

it should work fine.

Comment: So I can't do it with generic IList? :O

Comment: @markzzz: You can do it with a *generic* `IList<T>`, but not a *non-generic* `IList`, because that doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Uhm...in fact my IList is IList<T> (so generic)...but .Skip doesnt works :O

Comment: Added type of my IList...maybe you can write an example? :)

Comment: if it should works on generic `IList<T>` I really dont' understand `why list.Skip(0).Take(10);` doesnt...

Comment: @markzzz: Well it looks like you've already got `IList<T>`, so it should work fine. Please give more detail than "doesnt works". A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: @markzzz: Ah, I've spotted something else which could be the problem, and which would have been obvious if you'd posted the exact error message to start with. See my edit.

Comment: Yes man, but my source is a IList<T>. Need I to cycle the whole list and put it to a IEnumerable each time? Waste of resources... (

Comment: @markzzz: I don't understand your comment. An `IList<T>` *is already* an `IEnumerable<T>`. Please give a clearer explanation of what you mean. If you want an `IList<T>` implementation of the results of a LINQ query you'll need to call `ToList` or `ToArray`.

Comment: Yeah .ToList() works fine at the end of skip and take! Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for my bad english man! Thanks for your time and helps!